# ExtJs ComboBox Refresh Selected (Raw) Value

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I have a combobox with store items ({ value, text}), and sometimes I need to update the texts. When I do that the selected value (text) is not updated.

Here is [the fiddle to illustrate](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cdt) and the code looks like below. We pick an item in the drop down then we click on update text. This will update the text in the drop down but not the combobox raw value.

[Update]: replaced model.set() with store.loadData()

```js
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create("Ext.form.Panel", {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            bodyPadding: 20,
            layout: "form",

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: "combobox",
                    itemId: "pickmin",
                    fieldLabel: "Test",
                    queryMode: "local",
                    store: {
                        fields: ["value", "text"],
                        data: [
                            { value: 1, text: "Text 1" },
                            { value: 2, text: "Text 2" },
                            { value: 3, text: "Text 3" },
                            { value: 4, text: "Text 4" },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],

            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Update Text",
                    handler: function (btn) {
                        const combo = btn.up("form").down("#pickmin");
                        const newData = []
                        combo.store.each(r => {
                            newData.push({
                                value: r.data.value,
                                text: r.data.text + "0"
                            });
                        });
                        combo.store.loadData(newData);
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
 r.set("text", r.data.text + "0");
```

to change the value in each record. Your button code has to be:

```
 buttons: [{
            text: "Update Text",
            handler: function (btn) {
                const combo = btn.up("form").down("#pickmin");
                combo.store.each(r => {
                    r.set("text", r.data.text + "0"); 
                });
            }
          }]
```

### Update

You can solve it with that code:

```
combo.getStore().on("load",
    function (store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
       combo.setValue(combo.getValue());
    },
    this
)
```

I have written a Sencha fiddle for you showing the solution: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3cf6

I glad if it helped! Please consider accepting the best answer.

Comment: what if I used a store reload() instead? I failed to explain that it is not just the text that can be updated. We can change the value too, but the scenario I am trying to address is that the selected item is stil in store but now have a different text value.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the solution

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to set the valueField and displayField Property for the combobox
The combobox attributes should be like this

```
 xtype: "combobox",
 itemId: "pickmin",
 valueField:"value",
 displayField :"text"
```

Now the rawValue can be fetched from the combobox

Comment: the default valueField and displayField are "value" and "text" respectively; and even if I set those the text is still not updated when I click on the button.